# Denormalize fails when trying to use idAttribute to generate id

Tags: normalizr

I am using following schema:

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';
import { guid } from '../utils/guid';

const track = new schema.Entity('audioTracks');

const audioClip = new schema.Entity('audioclips', {
  audioclips: [track],
  }, {
   idAttribute: (entity, parent) => `${parent.id}:${entity.id}`,
});

const segment = new schema.Entity('segments', {
    audioclips: [audioClip],
  }
);

const program = new schema.Entity('programs', {
  segments: [segment],
});

const json = new schema.Entity('jsons', {
  programs: [program],
});

export const portalAttributes = new schema.Entity('portalAttributes');

export const experience = new schema.Entity('experiences', {
  json,
  portalAttributes,
});
```

My data uses same id's in the audioclip part, which I don't want to merge. Since they will contain unique data eventually.
The normalize part worked as expected, however when I try to denormalize data back it fails with following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at EntitySchema.idAttribute (http://localhost:4040/main.bundle.js:3782:59)
    at EntitySchema.getId (http://localhost:4040/vendor.bundle.js:70706:19)
    at unvisitEntity (http://localhost:4040/vendor.bundle.js:4787:19)
    at unvisit (http://localhost:4040/vendor.bundle.js:4821:14)
    at http://localhost:4040/vendor.bundle.js:70589:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at denormalize (http://localhost:4040/vendor.bundle.js:70588:37)
```

Please help denormalize data back.

All I do at this stage is:

```
const normalized = normalize(payload, norm.experience);
const denorm = denormalize(normalized.result, norm.experience, normalized.entities)
```

I can provide the input data as well on demand, it is kinda large.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a pull request out to fix this precise issue that I also ran into. I would suggest you comment on it that you also would like this solution so that it can be merged! https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/pull/294